# WHAT DOES THIS MEAN GUYS?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, math

No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

1.

## SELECT AVG(price) FROM car;

ERROR:  function avg(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AVG(price) FROM car;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

2.

## SELECT SUM(price) FROM car;

ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(price) FROM car;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

## SELECT ROUND(AVG(price)) FROM car;

ERROR:  function avg(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ROUND(AVG(price)) FROM car;
                     ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
igreen=#

Comment: Those aren't MySQL errors. Possibly PostgreSQL

Comment: Those appear to be homework questions.  Please post your code so we might be able to assist you.

Comment: Is price a ```NUMBER```?

Comment: Were you expected to write these functions?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. A good start would be the section on how to write a title that summarizes the specific problem.

Comment: @Mallam . . . The error seems very, very clear.  Could you explain what you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Because `avg()` and `sum()` aggregations are not used for `string` type variables. e.g. cannot have arguments of `string` type.

You need to use `numeric` type arguments instead.